# JList not showing items or showing selectively

Tags: java, swing, jlist, datamodel

I have a Java Swing application using a JList to show some data from a DB.

I am using DefaulListModel as the data model for the list in this way:

```
void PopulateSoldiersList() 
{
      try
      {
           soldiersListModel = new DefaultListModel();
           for (Soldier i : myBackEnd.GetAllSoldiers())
           {
                 soldiersListModel.addElement(i);
           }
           this.listSoldiers.setModel(soldiersListModel);
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {// Error Message}
}
```

And for some reason, the list just stays empty...

I even did make sure at runtime that all the data is set up properly in the data model and even in the "dataModel" property of the JList!

In other place at the app i have a similar problem, but there, sometimes the list show few items from the model (but not all of them)

I have no idea where to go from here...

please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Does your `Soldier` class have a `toString` method defined?

Comment: Is this list already visible when you are doing this? Or is this at initialization time?

Comment: Yes of course. The list is visible and i implemented toString. the weirdest thing is that until an hour ago it worked perfectly and then it just stop showing the items

Comment: You're not working outside the Swing thread I assume?

Comment: Did you validate and/or repaint the list after you reset the model? http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4113377 (it's not a bug, but described here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm.

I really need to kill myself.

I have another list, and i used similar methods to populate both lists.

Actually they so similar that i just copy-pasted the method i posted above - to populate the other list.

In my infinite wisdom i forgot to change only one thing: the name of the list which i'm setting the data model for...

So i ended up with two methods that populate the same list: the firs one with valid data, and the second just override it with empty data.

and guess in what order i called the methods...

```
myBackEnd = new DBBackEnd();
initComponents();
PopulateSoldiersList();
PopulateMissionsList();
```

No more copy-paste for me!

Comment: When you are copy and pasting a section of code and changing just a variable name. I suggest you stop and think (should this just me a method that I call multiple times intead?).

Comment: Yeah you are right. usually i do exactly what you would expect - make one generic method. but since each list is populated from different data source, i decided to write different method for each one.

Comment: I really learned in real life projects, that copy and paste is more than evil. You should really inspect line by line, every time.